# Passing in a lambda to a Where statement

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, lambda, expression, linq-expressions

I noticed today that if I do this:

```
var items = context.items.Where(i => i.Property < 2);
items = items.Where(i => i.Property > 4);
```

Once I access the items var, it executes only the first line as the data call and then does the second call in memory.  However, if I do this:

```
var items = context.items.Where(i => i.Property < 2).Where(i => i.Property > 4);
```

I get only one expression executed against the context that includes both where statements.  I have a host of variables that I want to use to build the expression for the linq lambda, but their presence or absence changes the expression such that I'd have to have a rediculous number of conditionals to satisfy all cases.  I thought I could just add the Where() statements as in my first example above, but that doesn't end up in a single expression that contains all of the criteria.  Therefore, I'm trying to create just the lambda itself as such:

```
//bogus syntax
if (var1 == "something")
    var expression = Expression<Func<item, bool>>(i => i.Property == "Something);
if (var2 == "somethingElse")
    expression = expression.Where(i => i.Property2 == "SomethingElse");
```

And then pass that in to the where of my context.Items to evaluate.  A) is this right, and B) if so, how do you do it?

EDIT:

```
IQueryable assessments = assessmentContext.Assessments;
metAssessments = metAssessments.Take(pageSize);
```

results in

```
SELECT [Fields] <== edited
FROM [dbo].[Assessment] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[AssessmentComment] AS [t1] ON [t1].[ID] = [t0].[AssessmentID] <== because of load options
```

Why no top x (as represented by pageSize)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What query provider are you using? For any reasonable provider, your first example should execute on the source (not in memory) as the conjunction of the two conditions in each of your `Where`s.

As for your question, no, that's not the right way to proceed to build an `Expression` manually. Your first definition is fine, but to build a conjunction you need to use [`Expression.AndAlso`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353520.aspx).

People have already wrapped this into a library for your usage. See [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx).

Comment: I was using IEnumerable<T> instead of IQueryable<T>.  Two different implementations of Where() apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) to construct your query dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that the reason that the first and second differ is that `items` has already accessed the data at that point. If you make the `items` object inherit from `IQueryable` you won't actually execute anything against the context until you actually access the items in the collection.

Comment: "I would imagine that the reason that the first and second differ is that items has already accessed the data at that point." No, it shouldn't as the query was never iterated over (at least as the code was presented to us).

Comment: @Jason, It's impossible this code use linq and first one executed and second one not, may be op see first one in quick watch and do ToList() and first one executed.